# Distributing MacOS apps outside the app store - Security & Piracy

Tags: macos, cocoa, app-store

I have am app that deals with sensitive information. I want to distribute this app using the App Store and also thru my own website.

I have two concerns:

1. Is there any difference in terms of security when an app is distributed outside the app store? I mean, is the information that the app deals or the app itself more vulnerable by not being code-signed for the App Store?
2. what about piracy? Is it easier to pirate an app that is distributed outside the app store? (considering an app that has no special counter-measures against piracy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. there is no difference. in both distributions you can adopt the sandbox to improve security.
2. in both distributions you'll have to implement your own license management. In appstore you can use the appstore receipt validation, outside you can choose whatever you like for licensing.

Comment: OK, I was just checking to see if I was getting it right. THANKS